# HTML Responsive Email

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, html-email

Using Litmus for responsive emails is showing great results for the majority of browsers, however some objects in the email are using `Display:none !important;` and are still showing up completely in Yahoo / Gmail, and partially in outlook 2013.

- Update : Providing example -

Using the styling code as following

> Basic Styling

.mobile {display: none; font-size:0; max-height: 0; line-height: 0; mso-hide:all;}

> @ Media

table[class=mobile] {display:block !important;line-height:1.5% !important; max-height: none !important; font-size: 12px !important;}

```
`<table class="mobile">
<tr>
<td>This should show up on mobile
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

`

On most browser via litmus only one or the other will show, but on Gmail it is showing both the mobile an the browser text

Comment: Not without details/examples, no.

Comment: If you figure out a foolproof way to get people to respond to your e-mails, please share it ;-)

Comment: @TylerH Responsive _subscribers_ are another challenge all together...

Comment: can we have some more information - what exactly are you trying to hide in your mail ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Example email code would be a great first step, combined with a screenshot of it rendering correctly and incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display` isn't supported in Outlook 2013 or googlemail - http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css

However `z-index` is. So you could try setting a negative `z-index`. I've not tested this, but worth a try.

Comment: Don't you need `position` to be able to use `z-index`?

Comment: Web clients like Gmail don't like `position` very much. Imagine what `position:fixed;` would do to the Gmail interface...

Comment: i've had trouble getting z-index to work right on outlook, I wouldn't recommend it. plus you have to do some mso conditionals to keep position from breaking everything else. It's much easier to wrap whatever section you planned on hiding in an `<!--[if !mso]><!--> ... <!--<![endif]-->`

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as your question is lacking in any relevant information i can only advise you.

1. Read and follow the information here 
   http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails/
   Especially note the point 
   99% of your CSS won't work (especially not in the browser-based email services like Gmail, Yahoo!Mail, etc.).
2. Avoid as much css as possible, code like its 1999 - yes use tables
3. IF you must use css, use inline, and what you cannot use inline put in the body and not the head.

So if you are trying to hide something ?? what we dont know - you need more to start thinking about things like white text on a white background.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your mobile tables in this:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<div class="mobileonly" style="display:none; width:0px; max-height:0px; overflow:hidden;">
    <!-- tables! -->
</div>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

then in your media query

```
div[class="mobileonly"] {
    display:block !important;
    overflow : visible !important;
    width:auto !important;
    max-height:inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post.

Solution is to use html tables to layout email content that will look and work well on outlook. Then wrapp the  columns in </td> </td> so that the td columns will be killed on other email client's like gmail, mobile emails etc.

This way you can create emails with two columns on outlook but wrap the columns on non outlook.